# ignore a specific \n character while still enabling the m flag

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to match characters across multiple lines so I enabled the m flag. However, I do not want to match a specific \n. Instead I want to match a space \s only. But it seems like the newline is matching spaces too:

```
 " 41\n6332 Hardin Rd, Bensalem, PA\n 19020" =~ /\s(\d+\s.+,.+,.+\d+)/m
 => 0 

" 41\n6332 Hardin Rd, Bensalem, PA\n 19020" =~ /\s(\d+[ ].+,.+,.+\d+)/m
 => 3
```

Even I try to explicitly ignore the newline:

```
" 41\n6332 Hardin Rd, Bensalem, PA\n 19020" =~ /\s(\d+[^\n].+,.+,.+\d+)/m
 => 0
```

Why is the newline matching a space character? And what can I do to ensure that it does not and still matches characters across multiple lines everywhere else?

Comment: What do you mean to say? "Newline matching a space"?? Sorry, but `"\n"` can't match a `" "`. What do you expect as a final result for `" 41\n6332 Hardin Rd, Bensalem, PA\n 19020"` input and why?

Comment: I do not want it to match a space, but it is. In the example above, it is matching. I do not want it to match if \n follows \d+. That is what I am trying to handle in the capturing group.

Comment: It matches because of those quantifiers. See, there is `4` and after it a `1` that is not a newline, so it matches. And you want to fail the whole match, right? Not sure, maybe you want to only match at the start of the string? Try  [`/\A\s*(\d++(?!\n).+,.+,.+\d)/m`](http://rubular.com/r/2ByPXGx3KI).

Comment: Yes this match is supposed to fail because of the \n after 41. I want to match a space after 41 not a newline.

Comment: Yes that solution worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/\s(\d+[^\n].+,.+,.+\d+)/m` pattern matches `" 41\n6332 Hardin Rd, Bensalem, PA\n 19020"` because when the regex engine gets to `[^\n]` after matching `41` with `\d+` backtracking occurs: the regex engine tries to match the string differently since it encountered `\n` and the next char should be a different char. So, it steps back to `\d+` and matches `4`, and `1` is not a newline, so matching continues.

You may anchor the search at the start of the string and prevent backtracking with a possessive quantifier, also implementing the negative check with a lookahead:

```
/\A\s*(\d++(?!\n).+,.+,.+\d)/m
```

See the [regex demo](http://rubular.com/r/qBGGgilLXS)

**Details**

- `\A` - start of string
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d++(?!\n).+,.+,.+\d)` - Capturing group 1:

  - `\d++(?!\n)` - 1+ digits (matched possessively with `++` quantifier) not followed with a newline (as `(?!\n)` is a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a newline immediately to the right of the current location)
  - `.+,.+,` - 2 occurrences of any 1+ chars as many as possible, followed with `,`
  - `.+\d` - any 1+ chars as many as possible followed with a digit.